# Linux Kernel: How to capture a key press and replace it with another key?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm attempting to dabble with low level programming. My goal is to have a user type a key into the terminal, capture that and output another key. So for example, if the user types "a" I would type out "b", if he types in "b" I output "c", etc.

What would be the steps to do that? I'm already familiar with how to access the Linux kernel source code, compile it, and use it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your user using X11, e.g. thru some desktop like Gnome, XFCE, KDE? You probably don't need to change kernel code (only to load some new keyboard map)

Comment: I believe he's doing this for educational purposes, trying to understand better the kernel development.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider next simple kernel module:

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <asm/io.h>

#define KBD_IRQ             1       /* IRQ number for keyboard (i8042) */
#define KBD_DATA_REG        0x60    /* I/O port for keyboard data */
#define KBD_SCANCODE_MASK   0x7f
#define KBD_STATUS_MASK     0x80

static irqreturn_t kbd2_isr(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    char scancode;

    scancode = inb(KBD_DATA_REG);
    /* NOTE: i/o ops take a lot of time thus must be avoided in HW ISRs */
    pr_info("Scan Code %x %s\n",
            scancode & KBD_SCANCODE_MASK,
            scancode & KBD_STATUS_MASK ? "Released" : "Pressed");

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int __init kbd2_init(void)
{
    return request_irq(KBD_IRQ, kbd2_isr, IRQF_SHARED, "kbd2", (void *)kbd2_isr);
}

static void __exit kbd2_exit(void)
{
    free_irq(KBD_IRQ, (void *)kbd2_isr);
}

module_init(kbd2_init);
module_exit(kbd2_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

This is most minimal and primitive [key-logger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging). It can be easily reworked for replacing of [scan code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode).

## Disclaimers

- This module is not cross-platform (will work only on x86 architecture, because it's using `inb()` function)
- I believe it only works with PS/2 keyboard (won't work with USB keyboard)
- It's performing slow I/O operation (I mean `pr_info()`) in hardware IRQ handler, which should be avoided (ideally [threaded IRQs](https://lwn.net/Articles/302043/) should be used)).

But I think it's good for educational purposes -- it's really small and demonstrates the idea pretty well (without messing with API like `input_dev`,  `input_register_device()`, `serio_write()`, `input_event()`, `input_report_key()`, etc).

## Details

Real interrupt handler (in [keyboard driver](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/serio/i8042.c#L1420)) requested as **shared interrupt**, which allows us also request that interrupt and thus handle it also in our [ISR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) (in addition to ISR in original keyboard driver). Interrupt requesting is done in `kbd2_init()`.

This module works as follows:

1. Catches key press event (hardware interrupt handler `kbd2_isr()` is called for each key press event)
2. Reads scan code of pressed key (via `inb()` function)
3. And prints it  via `pr_info()`

Now, you want to replace that scan code. I believe you can use `outb()` function for this (on x86). So I leave it for you.

If you wonder why we are requesting IRQ with number 1, see at [drivers/input/serio/i8042-io.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/serio/i8042-io.h#L18):

```c
#else
# define I8042_KBD_IRQ  1
```

Also be sure to check that this IRQ is shared in [drivers/input/serio/i8042.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/serio/i8042.c#L1420):

```c
error = request_irq(I8042_KBD_IRQ, i8042_interrupt, IRQF_SHARED,
                    "i8042", i8042_platform_device);
```

Here is documentation for i8042 keyboard controller: [AT keyboard controller](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-11.html).

## Useful constants

To avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), you can use next definitions.

From [drivers/input/serio/i8042-io.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/serio/i8042-io.h#L41):

```c
/*
 * Register numbers.
 */

#define I8042_COMMAND_REG       0x64
#define I8042_STATUS_REG        0x64
#define I8042_DATA_REG          0x60
```

From [include/linux/i8042.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/i8042.h):

```c
/*
 * Status register bits.
 */

#define I8042_STR_PARITY        0x80
#define I8042_STR_TIMEOUT       0x40
#define I8042_STR_AUXDATA       0x20
#define I8042_STR_KEYLOCK       0x10
#define I8042_STR_CMDDAT        0x08
#define I8042_STR_MUXERR        0x04
#define I8042_STR_IBF           0x02
#define I8042_STR_OBF           0x01
```

Comment: @0andriy Frankly, I just used the same approach as in `drivers/input/serio/i8042-io.h`. What are the benefits of `readb()` over `inb()` anyway?

Comment: @0andriy Heh, good to know :) But I'm not sure that that particular driver (i8042) is going to work on any arch other than x86.

Comment: Great answer! Why does this module not work with USB keyboards, though?

Comment: @étale-cohomology It's hard-coded to work with i8042 keyboard controller interrupt. AFAIK it's only being called for PS/2 keyboards. If you want to experiment with keyboard code, it's better to grab PS/2 keyboard for starters (much more easier to start coding, as opposed to USB keyboards).